# How to make a large section of html fade using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, element

I am using html right now and I want to make my whole page fade in and fade out on a command through jQuery (whether its click animate etc...).

I thought of using a large fixed div over everything but won't that obscure everything else being clicked?

I also thought I could wrap everything in a span but that won't work.

Finally, I understand I can fade **"body"**, but sometimes I want to fade large sections specifically *within* the body. Thank you for your help.

Comment: indeed wrap with a Div ?

Comment: but would the user still be able to interact and seletc text and click buttons?

Comment: `('.element').fadeOut()` this?

Comment: read http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may wanna use ids

```
<div id="object">content</div>

<script> $("#object").fadeOut(); </script>
```

Or with classes:

```
<div class="object">content</div>

<script> $(".object").fadeOut(); </script>
```

Comment: Looks good, but will the user still be able to click and do all the normal functions like the div isn't there?

Comment: Well if you hide specific content, the user may not be able to interact with that content because he cannot see it. The non hidden content should work normal

Comment: Okay. What I was planning to do was have a white div then change the opacity on command, but was just wondering if it would work that way. Thanks! I will mark this the correct answer when the 6 minutes runs out.